# TinyMCE wordpress, custom button does not show up

Tags: wordpress, button, tinymce

I created a plugin in wordpress to add a button to the TinyMCE. I have at the moment the code below which follows very strictly the example here: 
https://www.gavick.com/blog/wordpress-tinymce-custom-buttons#tc-section-1

**Php file**

```
< ? php
    /*
    Plugin Name: TinyMCE Custom Buttons
    Plugin URI:
    Description:
    Version:
    Author:
    Author URI:
    License:
    License URI:
    */

    //Hook the button on init, so after loading wordpress
    add_action('init', 'add_button1234');

    //add filters within th function which loads after loading wordpress
    function add_button1234() {
        // add new buttons
        add_filter('mce_buttons', 'myplugin_register_buttons1234');
        // Load the TinyMCE plugin 
        add_filter('mce_external_plugins', 'register_1234');
    }


    //Add the newly created button to ithe $buttons array
    function register_1234($buttons) {
        array_push($buttons, 'separator', 'button1234');
        return $buttons;
    }

    //create the button
    function myplugin_register_tinymce_javascript1234($plugin_array) {
        $plugin_array['button1234'] = plugins_url('plugin.js', __FILE__);
        return $plugin_array;
    }
?>
```

**javascript file**

```
(function() {
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('button1234', function(editor, url) {
        editor.addButton('button1234', {
            text: 'My test button',
                icon : false,
                onclick : function() {
                editor.insertContent('Hello World!');
            }
        });
    });
})();
```

Also when I follow exactly the code from the site (only adapting the JS url, it doesn't work.) What could I possible have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might not be calling the right function when adding the filter `mce_buttons` in the `add_button1234()` function.

Change this line:

```
add_filter( 'mce_buttons', 'myplugin_register_buttons1234' );
```

To:

```
add_filter( 'mce_buttons', 'myplugin_register_tinymce_javascript1234' );
```

Comment: Thank you, I did that and all buttons on the visual tinyMCE went blank. (so no more buttons) Any idea how this comes?

Comment: Do you have the path to your JavaScript file set properly on the line `$plugin_array['button1234'] = plugins_url('plugin.js', __FILE__);`?

Comment: The "plugin.js" file is in the same directory as the .php file so I guess it is correct.